# Send and receive data through one channel on different Go package/file

Tags: go

```
+----------------+                       +-----------------+
| Channel foo    |                       | Channel foo     |
| a.go           |                       | b.go            |
+----------------+                       +-----------------+
       |                                          |
       |__________________________________________|
        Send or receive data through 'foo' channel
```

Can I create two Go source code files and send or receive data through one channel such as described from image/illustration above? So, these files could communicate each other with sending data while source code is running.

Comment: Yes you can. This is just an idea. If it's in same package, you can define package scope channel then do send and receive. If it's different package pass the channel as parameter to the Method you want to send/receive. Implement it as per your need.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'll try this.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Channels are just variables in Go, like `int`, `[]byte` or `bool`.  If you can pass any variables between packages, you can obviously then pass channels between packages as well.  And once you've passed a channel from one package to another, you are of course free to use it there, just as you would any other variable.  That means you can send data in one package, and receive it in another.

Ultimately channels wouldn't be very useful if they couldn't be shared between packages.